# Select next row when Enter is pressed while editing a NSTextField inside a NSTableView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield

I set some `NSTextField`s inside my view-based `NSTableView` to be editable, and to send an action on "end editing" (so when Enter or Tab is pressed, or when the focus is lost). The behavior when hitting Tab is perfect: the cell on the right of the current one gets selected and is ready to be edited. Same goes for Shift+Tab. When hitting Enter, the field is "deactivated" but the same row stays selected, which is the normal behavior. 
What I want to achieve is a vertical version of what Tab does, with the Enter key.

To be clear: I'm editing a `NSTextField` inside my table. I hit Enter. I want the next row to become selected, and the field in the same column that I was editing previously should become "activated" (meaning it turns into an editable `NSTextField` with its current content highlighted). The action should still be triggered normally, like it would if you hit Tab while editing a cell.

Is that possible? If yes, how would I proceed?

I thought about subclassing `NSTextField` and playing with `keyDown` a little, but I think I would then have to use the notification center to trigger a callback that would make the row selection change in my table and the activation of the next table cell. This seems like overkill, and I wouldn't know how to make the latter happen (activate the NSTextField for editing).

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you select the next row in your action?

Comment: @Willeke because I don't want to select the next row if the action was triggered by a click outside of the field or the user hitting the Tab key

Comment: In the action you can get the current event [NSApp currentEvent] and check for enter.

Comment: @Willeke thanks for this, I didn't try it since Marc's solution from below worked for me, and it allowed to block the default behavior and filtering of the command that was typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the NSControlTextEditingDelegate method

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)command
```

with the text field to detect the enter key and

```
- (void)editColumn:(NSInteger)columnIndex row:(NSInteger)rowIndex withEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent select:(BOOL)flag
```

to select the next row in the table view.

Comment: Thanks for this, I managed to do what I want using both these methods. May I add that, in the first method, I had to return true if the selector was `insertNewline:`, return false otherwise (to not affect the other behaviors). Then, I additionally used `selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:` from `NSTableView` to select the next row before calling `editColumn`.

Comment: Can you share the code that worked for you?  I am having the same issue and cannot resolve

Answer (score -1):

There are two steps that you need to kill your problem.

1. Trigger when return button is pressed. You can use *textFieldShouldReturn* method of **UITextFieldDelegate** to finish this step.
2. Inside the method that you used at step 1, select next row in your tableView.

   `NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];
   [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: nextIndexPath
                           animated:YES 
                     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
   [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: nextIndexPath];`

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Swift on Cocoa so UITextFieldDelegate doesn't exist and the code in point 2 is gibberish for me. I found `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` but it doesn't have a similar method. There is `control:textShouldEndEditing` but it doesn't make the difference between the Enter key or another key/losing focus.